# Flutter refreshing tokens at the same time

Tags: flutter, dart

In the case of requests are not sent async and the responses are 401 status code, the refresh token operation is called as many times as sync requests. How to solve it? Is the only solution to send all requests synchronously?

```
 Future: Future.wait(
  [
   _restApi.getUserName(),
   _restApi.getUserLastName(),
   _restApi.getUserNick(),
  ],

 class AppAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
      @override
      FutureOr<Request?> authenticate(Request request, Response response,
          [Request? originalRequest]) async {
        if (response.statusCode == 401) {
          //refresh token and repeat request with new token
        }
        return null;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use queued interceptor from the [dio package](https://pub.dev/packages/dio#queuedinterceptor). This allows the functionality you are looking for!